# Setting a property on an object resets the same property on similar objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, collections

In the code section below, I should have an ArrayList of Objs with different xValues. Instead, when I set the xValue of the Obj n on the fourth line, all Objs with the same name in the ArrayList get the xValue set to the same value.

```
Obj n = new Obj();
n = getObj(event.getX(), event.getY(), view.getHeight(), view.getWidth(), view);

n.setXValue(view.getWidth());

if (currentMode == AppMode.MODE.code && n != null) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        arraylist.add(n);
    } // end if (event.getAction
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a collection which will allow me to set properties of an object without messing up properties of other objects in the collection?

Comment: You can't expect good debugging without showing the `Obj` class.  One odd thing I see: in the first line, you create a new `Obj` but then you immediately throw it away and replace it with the result of `getObj(...)`.  Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is a "pass-by-reference" language when it comes to Objects.  When you put the same Object in two different collections, you're just passing a pointer to the same spot in memory to each collection, so any changes you make from one reference will affect the other reference.

If you don't desire this behavior, you have to use Object.clone() to make copies of the objects before putting them in new collections, or use some other similar copying technique.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you wrote Obj and within Obj you have a static variable named something like XValue.

When you designate a variable as static you get one and only instance of that variable shared across all instances of that class, hence: this behavior.

Or, what torquestomp said (he's right)

Comment: No, xValue isn't static, and the xValue is not reset for all Objs, just ones with the same 'name' property.